# Find the number of ways to put the balls into the boxes with no restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of ways to put the 7 balls (Distinct) into the 3 boxes (Indistinguishable) without any restrictions ?

---

Can I apply stirling formula of 2nd kind in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, Stirling numbers of the second kind give you the correct answer for this one:

> The Stirling numbers of the second kind, written ${\displaystyle S(n,k)}$ or ${\displaystyle \lbrace \textstyle {n \atop k}\rbrace }$ or with other notations, count the number of ways to partition a set of ${\displaystyle n}$ labelled objects into ${\displaystyle k} $ nonempty unlabelled subsets

You have no restrictions so I assume you can have empty boxes. Therefore the total number of ways will be

*n.o of ways to put all balls in 1 box* + *n.o of ways to put all balls in 2 boxes* + *n.o of ways to put all balls in 3 boxes*.

There is only 1 way of having everything in the same box. Using the stirling numbers, there are $S(7, 2) $ ways of having the balls in 2 different boxes and $S(7, 3) $ ways of having them split between 3 boxes. Now just use the recurrence formula to calculate it.

Comment: Can you please show ?

Comment: Done. Yoy should now be able to finish the exercise

Comment: Usually, we apply stirling such that no box is empty, but we can still apply like this right ?

Comment: You can because we took separately each case into consideration: 2 boxes empty, 1 box empty and no boxes empty

Comment: Yes thanks for clarification !! Okk just one more doubt, What if the boxes are distinguishable ? I know then it is 3^7, but i want to know with stirling numbers. I think we need to multiply all the cases by r!. Am i right ?

Comment: For both distinct, it is =>  1!. S(7,1) + 2!. S(7,2)  + 3! .S(7,3) = 1933, but the answer is 2187. Can you please rectify me ?

Comment: @Willturner yeah sure: i made a mistake. For 2 empty boxes you have $S(7,1) $ 1-partitions and then you have ${3\choose {1}} $ ways of deciding where to put it: $3\cdot S(7,1) $. For 1 empty box you have $S(7, 2) $ partitions and ${3\choose {2}} $ ways of distributing them hence making ${3\choose {2}}\cdot S(7,2) $ ways. Similarly for $S(7, 3) $

Comment: Still not getting 2187.

Comment: You must have a problem in your calculations, probably in the calculation of some Sterling number. Ensure you are computing $3S(7,1) + 3×2S(7,2) + 3! S(7,3) $ and that $S(7,1)=1, S(7,2)=73, S(7,3)=301$.

Comment: My Bad !! Got it now . Thanks for both the questions.